# What is the first fictional container that is magically smaller on the inside?

Tags: history-of, magical-items

A container that is magically larger on the inside than on the outside is something that appears more or less often in fiction. What is the first fictional container that, for some reason or another (maybe just humor) is magically *smaller* on the inside?

Comment: I've got a foam camp cooler that's a couple inches smaller inside than its outside dimension.  This isn't fictional, it's just wall thickness...

Comment: @ZeissIkon That's why I explicitely said magical. Obviously this is probably going to be humorous, like a large building that turns out to just be a small closet or something.

Comment: Are they _any_ examples?

Comment: Although it may have made it technically on-topic, I don't think the edit to make this a "history of" question makes any sense, unless we have at least one recent example up front. Whatever wording, the question right now is "has this joke ever been made?"

Comment: Just had a trawl through (TV Tropes Warning) [Bigger on the inside](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BiggerOnTheInside) and they didn't have any links to a reverse trope.

Comment: @OrangeDog The only thing close I can think of is the shrinking hallway in Willy Wonka's factory, but that is an optical illusion not magic.

Comment: I don't actually know if there is an example, but it's something I would expect from stuff like Discworld or Hitchhikers guide to the galaxy

Comment: Alice in Wonderland --  The world through the door is smaller, no? The tears created an ocean. . .

Comment: @IMSoP if it’s not a [[tag:history-of]] question looking for first it is off topic as any questions are off topic. I also remember a humorous example of this but can’t recall what.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Well, yes, that was kind of my point: just editing "first" into the title doesn't stop it being a speculative "has this been done?"

Comment: @IMSoP I understood your point; I just don’t think it applies here. An answer saying there aren’t any isn’t really an answer to the question and if it’s acceptable as an answer then that’s fine also. That said thinking about it more this sounds like something Pratchett may have done.

Comment: Deceptively large packaging is a pretty common trope. Not sure magic is needed though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably not the first example, but in [Howl's Moving Castle](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6294.Howl_s_Moving_Castle) by Diana Wynne Jones the titular castle itself is much smaller on the inside than the outside. Outside it appears to be a "great, ugly castle", "far too tall for its height" "built of huge black blocks" but inside there is just a quite small workroom-cum-kitchen, a bathroom, and two bedrooms up a rickety flight of stairs. The interior is actually that of an entirely different smallish house, connected to the castle exterior by magic.

Comment: Might want to add that this book was written in 1986.

Answer (score 2):

One example that comes to mind is **John Malkovich**.

[image: Malkovich Malkovich]

In the 1999 movie [Being John Malkovich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Being_John_Malkovich), characters who go to the seven-and-a-halfth floor of the Mertin-Flemmer building find themselves in a miniature office building floor (literally, not magically, smaller, so far as we know).  But within that floor is a small door, and entering that door puts the visitor behind the eyes of John Malkovich.  As in the image above, the visitor sees through the eyes as if they were a portal in front of them - the visitor is, in some magical way, small enough to fit behind John Malkovich's eyes.

Comment: I think the visual effect is for the benefit of the audience, rather than a true representation of the character's experience. Much of the plot hinges on the fact that going through the door allows you to actually control John Malkovich, not just see through his eyes. It's more a case of _possession_ than shrinking.

Answer (score -1):

Although I am not sure it's exactly what you are looking for, The Logical Magician series from 1995 has a mathematician using his mathematical knowledge to great effect when he is introduced to magic, it turns out being able to naturally think and reason in altered geometric spaces and higher dimensions is fantastic for magic innovation. At some point an actual Klein bottle is created, which is a closed bottle that takes up space but has zero volume. It's impossible to create in 3 dimensions without magic.

I would not be surprised if there was an earlier work that played off of the novel geometry of Klein bottles as well.

Comment: This doesn't say anything about a container that's magically smaller inside than outside.  A Klein bottle technically *has no* inside or outside.

Comment: Having no inside in a way that can only be achieved via magic seems like it would fit. It's much smaller than expected  and it is achieved via magic.